# Homeomorphism between interiors of simplex and permutohedron

Tags: convex-polytopes, polytopes, compactifications, configuration-spaces

The $n$-dimensional [permutohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron) $P_n$ is a polytope whose facets (i.e.\ codimension $1$ faces) are in 1-to-1 correspondence with all faces (of codimension${}\geq 1$) of the $n$-simplex $\Delta_n$, and can be obtained from $\Delta_n$ by [omnitruncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnitruncation). For example, $P_2$ is the hexagon, and $P_3$ is obtained from the tetrahedron $\Delta_3$ by first truncating at each vertex and then truncating along each of the $6$ original edges (not the edges created by the first truncation).

For some problems related to configuration spaces, I would like to know:

**It there a known homeomorphism between the interiors $\operatorname{int}(P_n)$ and $\operatorname{int}(\Delta_n)$, with the property that when a point in $\operatorname{int}(P_n)$ goes to some facet, its image in $\operatorname{int}(\Delta_n)$ goes to the corresponding face?**

$\partial P_n$ can be collapsed onto $\partial\Delta_n$. Intuitively, you might think of building the required homeomorphism by extending this collapsing to the interior. But it is quite delicate to show that it does extend. So I'm wondering whether it is already done in the literature.

Comment: What do you mean by "a point in $\mathrm{int}(P_n)$ goes to some facet"?

Comment: @RichardStanley: I think this means if we have a sequence of points in the interior converging to a point on the boundary (hence on some facet of the permutohedron), the image of this sequence should be a sequence converging to a point on the corresponding face of the simplex.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: Exactly.